# Re-import modules in function definition or using Try - except?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Which is more elegant of these two:

Importing the module anyway:

```
def shuffle_sequence(seq):
    import random
    seq = list(seq)
    random.shuffle(seq)
    return ''.join(seq)
```

Or use Try block to do it:

```
def shuffle_sequence(seq):
    seq = list(seq)
    try:
        random.shuffle(seq)
    except NameError:
        import random
        random.shuffle(seq)
    return ''.join(seq)
```

Comment: How do you find yourself in this situation?

Comment: Note that `import` will cache the existing module, so it is not costly to reimport an already imported modules. In fact the `try`-`except` block may add more overhead than that...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta *<shudders>*

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

Import at the top of the module always as desribed in the [**python style guide**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)! I can't imagine any situation where you need to reload a module and if you do then look at [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)

```
import random

# other code

def shuffle_sequence(seq):
    seq = list(seq)
    random.shuffle(seq)
    return ''.join(seq)
```